# Error-correcting loop in C++, find specific chars in a string and flag as bad input

Tags: c++

Here is v1.0 of the binary_to_decimal converter I wrote.  I want to make several changes as I keep improving the spec.  Classes and pointers will be added as well in the future.  Just to keep me fresh and well practiced.

Well, I now want to implement an error-correcting loop that will flag any character that is not a 0 or a 1 and ask for input again.

I have been trying something along the line of this code block that worked with an array.
It might be way off but I think I can tweak it.  I am still learning 0_0

I want to add something like this:

```
    while ((cin >> strint).get())
        {
            cin.clear();  //reset the input
            while (cin.get() != '\n')  //clear all the way to the newline char
                continue; //
            cout << "Enter zeroes and/or ones only! \n";
        }
```

Here is the final code without the error-correcting loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 100;

int conv(int z[MAX], int l[MAX], int a);

int main()
{
    int zelda[MAX];
    int link[MAX];
    string strint;
    int am;

    cout << "Enter a binary number: \n";
    (cin >> strint).get();  //add error-correction to only read 0s and 1s.
    am = strint.size();
    cout << am << " digits entered." << endl;

    int i = 0;
    int p = 0;
    while (i < am)
    {
        zelda[i] = strint[p] - '0';     //copies the string array elements into the int array; essentially STRING TO INT (the minus FORCES a conversion because it is arithmetic) <---- EXTREMELY CLEVER!
        ++i;
        ++p;
    }   

    cout << conv(zelda, link, am);

    cin.get();
    return  0;
}


int conv(int zelda[MAX], int link[MAX], int length)
{   
    int sum = 0;
    for (int t = 0; t < length; t++)
    {
        long int h, i;
        for (int h = length - 1, i = 0; h >= 0; --h, ++i)
            if (zelda[t] == 1)
                link[h] = pow(2.0, i);
            else
                link[h] = 0;
            sum += link[t]; 
    }
    return sum;
}
```

thanks guys.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but the answer is probably to use more meaningful identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure of what you're trying to do, but I *think* what you're wanting is [`string::find_first_not_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/). There's an example included in that link. You could have something like: `myString.find_first_not_of("01");`

If the return value is `string::npos`, then there are no characters in the string other than 1 or 0, therefore it's valid. If the return value is anything else, then prompt again for valid input and continue looping until the input's valid.

Comment: I am trying to get the program to ask me for correct input.  Let's say I type in "1211111".  This should cause the program to halt and wait for input that has zeros and ones only.  (binary).  Legit examples would be: 0000000, 1111111, 00011, 11011, etc...

Comment: @Duknov007: Ok, I thought so. Read the line into a `string` and the above should do what you're wanting.